# ¿Cómo obtener los elementos de un iframe en local sin servidores?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, ajax

¡¡¡Hola Comunidad!!!

Tengo el siguiente problema:
Me pidieron hacer una base de datos para después obtener un reporte, el problema es que la única fuente que tengo para sacar los datos en un reporte en HTML que hace un controlador de acceso de puertas, es muy sencillo en cuanto a la estructura:

```
<body>
    <table></table>
    <table></table>
    <table></table>
</body>
```

Literal así es, se me ocurrió ponerlo en un iframe y después acceder a él para obtener los datos de las tablas y guardarlo en un JSON pero me encuentro con el famosísimo error "Cross Origin null" que básicamente por seguridad no me deja acceder al iframe para obtener los datos.

Intenté esto con JQuery:

```
$("#id_description_iframe").contents().find("body").html()
```

Pero no funciono e intente hacerlo con AJAX y tampoco por el mismo problema.

No puedo subirlo a internet porque en la empresa no les dan acceso a internet.

Con AJAX no tengo problema al momento de subirlo a Localhost y obtener el HTML.

Así que si alguien conoce una forma de que sea solo con Javascript, les agredeceria mucho.

Comment: Te recomendaria usar `cheerio` junto con `nodejs` ya que este te recolecta la informacion `HTML` de una pagina web que le especifiques, solo debes seleccionar de acuerdo a etiquetas, clases o ids, realmente no necesitas un iframe para todo eso, de hecho podrias hacer lo siguiente, como frontend usar javascript (nada del otro mundo, seria HTML y JS a lo mucho CSS), y para el backend (el que le devolvera la informacion al frontend), usarias `nodejs` junto con `cheerio`, tambien axios dicen que es muy bueno, pero ni me acuerdo para que sirve.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías hacer un fetch con javascript y luego insertar ese html en una div y ahí trabajar con un DOM al que puedas hacerle querySelector.

```
funcionqueleehtml = () => 
{
 fetch('/url/al/server/local')
 .then(res => {
    return res.text();
  })
  .then(data => {
     $('#contenedor').html(data);
  });
}
```